# How to Access a Shared Preference Data anywhere in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I need to access a data throughout my Project.For this I have created shared preferences.Below is my code

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getSharedPreferences(My_PREFS_FileName,MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("mobile", phonenumber_str);
            editor.commit();
```

Now to access this data I have written below code

```
SharedPreferences editor=getSharedPreferences(My_PREFS_FileName,MODE_PRIVATE);
String mobile=editor.getString("mobile",null);
```

It is working in the same page I have the code but I need to access my shared preference  `mobile` in different pages but I can not. How to do that

Comment: you can make a seperate utils class (e.g SharedPreferenceUtils.java) which can contain a static public method named getMobile(). That method can contain the above code (for retrieval of phone number). You can call that method from anywhere.

Comment: Set up a repository singleton that exposes your data to the rest of your app, and have that singleton use `SharedPreferences` (or whatever) as its data store.